# DataTable with no data

Tags: r, shiny

It must be late because I can't figure this out. When I run the Shiny app below the DataTable appears blank.

Could you help me spot my mistake please?

As far as I know `df_filtered` should return `df` if no input is selected. And the it is called as a reactive function by `renderDataTable`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

# Test data
LANZ <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
TIPO <- c('V5', 'V5', 'V10', 'V10', 'V10')
PROY <- c('1', '2', '2', '2', '3')
YEAR <- c(2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019)
df <- data.frame(LANZ, TIPO, PROY, YEAR)
colnames(df)[1] <- "LANZ"
colnames(df)[2] <- "TIPO"
colnames(df)[3] <- "PROY"
colnames(df)[4] <- "YEAR"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    
    wellPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(4, selectInput("idYearD", "", selected=NULL, multiple=FALSE, choice=c('Year' = '', c("2019","2020")))),
        column(4, selectInput("idTipo", "", selected=NULL, multiple=FALSE, choice=c('Tipo' = '', c("V5","V10")))),
        column(4, selectInput("idProy", "", selected=NULL, multiple=FALSE, choice=c('Proy' = '', c("1","2","3")))
        )),

      fluidRow(
        column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('dataTable'))
      ))
))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df_filtered <- reactive({
    
    data_df <- df
    if (!is.null( input$idYearD ) ) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(YEAR %in% input$idYearD)
    }
    if (!is.null( input$idTipo )) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(TIPO %in% input$idTipo)
    }
    if (!is.null( input$idProy )) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(PROY %in% input$idProy)
    }
    data_df
  })
  
  output$dataTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    df_filtered()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Up front:** `is.null` is not catching the fact that `input$idYearD` can be (and starts as) the empty string, `""`. Use either `!is.null(.) && nzchar(.)` or `shiny::isTruthy(.)`.

**Side note:** `input$idYearD` is a string, whereas your `YEAR` is a number. R is doing the intuitive thing by inferring the comparison (casting/coercing), but you need to be aware that this is doing a string comparison, not a numeric one. It works *here*. This is more impactful when dealing with floating-point and/or order of things, as `<` and `>` (and `sort` and `order` ...) are doing *alphabetic* comparisons ... `"11" < 2` is counter-intuitively true.

---

What I did was interject `browser()` in your `df_filtered` reactive block:

```r
  df_filtered <- reactive({
    browser()
    # ...
  })
```

From there, on execution, testing

```r
!is.null( input$idYearD )
# [1] TRUE
input$idYearD
# [1] ""
```

So perhaps this block instead:

```r
  df_filtered <- reactive({
    
    data_df <- df
    if ( isTruthy( input$idYearD ) ) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(YEAR %in% input$idYearD)
    }
    if ( isTruthy( input$idTipo ) ) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(TIPO %in% input$idTipo)
    }
    if ( isTruthy( input$idProy ) ) {
      data_df <- data_df %>% filter(PROY %in% input$idProy)
    }
    data_df
  })
```

Alternatively (and more compactly), you could do:

```r
  df_filtered <- reactive({
    df %>%
      filter(
        !isTruthy( input$idYearD ) | YEAR %in% input$idYearD,
        !isTruthy( input$idTipo ) | TIPO %in% input$idTipo,
        !isTruthy( input$idProy ) | PROY %in% input$idProy
      )
  })
```

Edited to remove `is.null`, since `isTruthy(NULL)` is the same as `!is.null(NULL)`.

If for some reason in your future `isTruthy` doesn't quite meet all of your needs, your original code could be augmented for just a string-specific comparison, as in

```r
    if (!is.null( input$idYearD ) && nzchar( input$idYearD )) {
```